Gather different pixels per image of an image stack with torch
I have a batch of images and a batch of indices (x, y) for each image. The indices are different for each image, so I cant use simple indexing. What is the best or fastest way to get another batch with the colors of the selected pixels per image?
    n_images = 4
    width = 100
    height = 100
    channels = 3
    n_samples = 30
    
    images = torch.rand((n_images, height, width, channels))
    indices = (torch.rand((n_images, n_samples, 2)) * width).to(torch.int32)

    # preferred function
    # result = images[indices]
    # with result.shape = (n_images, n_samples, 3)



    

    # I just found this solution but I would rather like to call a general torch function
    xs = indices.reshape((-1, 2))[:, 0]
    ys = indices.reshape((-1, 2))[:, 1]
    ix = torch.arange(n_images, dtype=torch.int32)
    ix = ix[..., None].expand((-1, n_samples)).flatten()
    
    result = images[ix, ys, xs].reshape((n_images, n_samples, 3))


You can use your indices tensor directly, you just need another tensor for the batch indexing:
n_images = 4
width = 100
height = 100
channels = 3
n_samples = 30

images = torch.rand((n_images, height, width, channels))
indices = (torch.rand((n_images, n_samples, 2)) * width).to(torch.int32)

batch_indices = torch.arange(n_images).view(-1, 1).expand(-1, n_samples)
result = images[batch_indices, indices[..., 1], indices[..., 0]]

This follows your convention of images[ix, ys, xs] where the ys index the height dimension of the tensor and the xs index the width

To use torch function, you will need to flatten the dimensions you need to calculate, as well as the indices, then you can use torch.gather to select the pixels you need:
n_images = 4
width = 100
height = 100
channels = 3
n_samples = 30

images = torch.rand((n_images, height, width, channels))
indices = (torch.rand((n_images, n_samples, 2)) * width).long() #<-- cast this to long instead of int as `torch.gather` requires long as index

flatten_images = images.view(n_images,-1, channels)
flatten_indices = (indices[..., 1:2] * width + indices[..., 0:1]).repeat(1,1,channels)
output = torch.gather(flatten_images, 1, flatten_indices).view(n_images, n_samples, channels) # 

